# Empty gaps between UITabBar elements?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbar

I'm having an issue with my UITabBar:

This is what it looks like in its different states:

[image]

As you can see, there's little empty areas between my elements and on the sides:

[image]

My Question is why isn't it like on the App Store app, where you do not have side or in between elements gaps?

[image]
[image]

And this is how I am changing the appearance of the Tab Bar, with a background image that does NOT have any dividers:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"UITabBarBG"]];
```

Following a method like explained here wouldn't work because of the gaps I have:
http://blog.erikvdwal.nl/blog/2012/09/25/customizing-the-uitabbar-in-ios-5-and-ios-6/

Any help would be helpful!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that the selected indicator image is the same size as the  tab?

Comment: Yes, it should adapt to the width of the element since I use this:     [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"UITabBarActiveSegment"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 4, 0, 4)]];

Answer (score 1):

If you make your images are larger you will not have this issue, they can even overlap if you want the same separators as in the AppStore app.

See [How can I add a custom divider image to the UITabBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572165/how-can-i-add-a-custom-divider-image-to-the-uitabbar)

Comment: Thanks. I thought I could have done it in an easier way than providing a static image for each buttons.

Comment: Yes, me too when I start customizing it, but it appears we cannot. And  [[UITabBar appearance] setSelectionIndicatorImage:image] dos not resize the image even if it's a resizable image.