# How to add Image On 'more' Button of UITabBarController in iOS 6?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

I know how to add `UITabBarController` and how it is used, I already done it.

My Problem is that I am not able to add image on `'more'` tab of `UITabBarController`.
I know there are many similar questions as mine but did not help me.
After googling I found that **we can't add images on `'More'` tab in `UITabBarController` Because `more` tab is automatically displayed by `UITabBarController` when `UITabBarItem` is more Then 5.**
I could find how to change **SELECTION COLOR AND TITLE OF** `'more'` button, But I could not find about `'more'` button Image.

So may be I need to customize `UITabBarController` so, I am also searching for customization of `UITabBarController` but could not find it.

Please help me on this Issue.

Comment: More button is automatically generate when tabs are more than 5 in iPhone .... So you cant do that ... instead you should make a custom tabbar with the help of `UIView` and `UIButton`s ...

Comment: @TheTiger- thanks for replay... i also tried to found custom tabBarController but i can not find it, if you have any link of source of code that please put here ..:)

Comment: check it and let me know if it is your demand http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2q2fuvp&s=5 then i will share code with you.

Comment: @BobApple- yes exactly i want this types of UITabBarController. please share code :)

Comment: did you solved the issue?

Comment: @BobApple- nope :( please put your code as answer ..it is very very important to me :)

Comment: ok let me show you code:)

Comment: first take a look http://stackoverflow.com/a/12572336/1328096 because i have using nearly same way like this but still if you face any problem then let me know.

Comment: i think still you did not solve the problem. if  you want to customize the tabbar like the image i show you then why you not following the approach i mentioned.

Comment: @iPatel - Please accept any answer.

Answer (score 5):

More button is automatically generate when tabs are more than 5 in iPhone. So you can't do that. Instead you should make a custom tabbar with the help of `UIView` and `UIButton`s.

See how to add `UIViewController`'s view on `self.view`.

```
[self addChildViewController:yourViewController];
yourViewController.view.frame = anyFrame;
[self addSubview:yourViewController.view];
[yourViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

By this you can add different `UIViewController` on each button's click. All the best! 

Well If you dont want to create it yourself. Below is the list of custom tabbars find the one which suits your requirement.

1. [AKTabBarController](https://github.com/alikaragoz/AKTabBarController)
2. [InfiniTabBar](https://github.com/iosdeveloper/InfiniTabBar)
3. [RaisedCenterTabBar](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar)
4. [MHTabBarController](https://github.com/hollance/MHTabBarController)
5. [TweetBotTabBar](https://github.com/i300/TweetBotTabBar)
6. [ALCustomTabBarController](https://github.com/aalittle/ALCustomTabBarController)
7. [MHCustomTabBarController](https://github.com/mhaddl/MHCustomTabBarController)
8. [M13InfiniteTabBar](https://github.com/Marxon13/M13InfiniteTabBar)
9. [TabBarKit](https://github.com/davidmorford/TabBarKit)
10. [RNSwipeBar](https://github.com/rnystrom/RNSwipeBar)
11. [BCTabBarController](https://github.com/briancollins/BCTabBarController)
12. [TabBarAnimation](https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/TabBarAnimation)
13. [ExpandableTabBar](https://github.com/brendandixon/ExpandableTabBar)
14. [JBTabBarController](https://github.com/jinthagerman/JBTabBarController)
15. [JSScrollableTabBar](https://github.com/jasarien/JSScrollableTabBar)
16. [NGTabBarController](https://github.com/NOUSguide/NGTabBarController)
17. [crtabbar](https://github.com/consumerreports/crtabbar)
18. [VSTabBar](https://github.com/vincentsaluzzo/VSTabBar)
19. [DMFilterView](https://github.com/Dimillian/DMFilterView)
20. [CubeTabBarController](https://github.com/augustjoki/CubeTabBarController)
21. [FSVerticalTabBarController](https://github.com/futuresimple/FSVerticalTabBarController)
22. [PrettyKit](https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit)

Answer (score 2):

You can add an image for each item , for the selected and unselected states. Like this:

```
UIImage *selectedImage0     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage0   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1_unselected.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage1     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage1   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2_unselected.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage2     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage2   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3_unselected.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage3     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage3   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4_unselected.png"];

UIImage *selectedImage4     = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image5.png"];
UIImage *unselectedImage4   = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image5_unselected.png"];

UITabBar     *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
UITabBarItem *item0  = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UITabBarItem *item1  = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
UITabBarItem *item2  = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];
UITabBarItem *item3  = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:3];
UITabBarItem *item4  = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4];

[item0 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage0 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage0];
[item1 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage1 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage1];
[item2 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage2 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage2];
[item3 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage3 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage3];
[item4 setFinishedSelectedImage:selectedImage4 withFinishedUnselectedImage:unselectedImage4];
```

You can place this code in the viewDidLoad method of any of your controllers.

Hope it works for you thanks!

Comment: Thanks for replay dude, may be you can't get my Question clearly.. I want to change image of 'more' button that by default come with UITabBarController and it would display when you have more than 5 tabBarItems.. :)

Comment: you only want to change the image of more tabbar item? but then what will do for others tabbar items.i think you need to Customize all the tabbar items this is only way you can change the image of more button.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create more than 5 segues from TabBarController to others and than you will see more button. Add images on the TabBar item of each controller you were connected and you will see this tabbar item's icon on the main TabBar

Comment: sorry i can not understand your answer... i have 6 TabBarItem and i also added image to each TabBarItem but but it not helpful to display image on more button :(