# iOS UITabViewItem divider & background color for selected TabItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

**How do you display a background color for the selected tab view?** I know that you can tint it when it's selected, however, I don't think this is of much use if you can not change the background color.

Also, how do you add a divider for each tab?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set an image as the background for the selection:

```
tabBarController.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
```

As for the dividers, prior to iOS 7 you could simulate them by adding an image for the selected state and another for the unselected state for each tab. See [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572165/how-can-i-add-a-custom-divider-image-to-the-uitabbar/12572336#12572336). Those methods were deprecated in iOS 7, though.

Comment: For the background of the TabBarItem. See my edit re: the divider.

Comment: and this image would simply be a solid color?

Comment: Yes, you can use a solid color and transparency will be applied.