# Add separator between section in TabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have to add separator between section in TabBar as in image below:
[image]

I tried to set the background image for tabbar using this image:
[image]
but I have problems when I rotate the device.

The code that I used:

```
 + (UITabBarController *)loadTabbar
 {
     UITabBarController *tabBarController = [UITabBarController new];
 
     MenuVC     *viewController0 = [MenuVC new];
     FavVC      *viewController1 = [FavVC new];
     UploadVC   *viewController2 = [UploadVC new];
     RestoreVC  *viewController3 = [RestoreVC new];
     SettingsVC *viewController4 = [SettingsVC new];
     
     tabBarController.viewControllers = @[viewController0, viewController1, iewController2, viewController3, viewController4];
     [tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage mageNamed:@"tabbar_color"]];
 
     [self setRootController:tabBarController];
     
     return  tabBarController;
 }
```

Also, I tried to add a separator on the right side of image that I used for abbar item but without result.
Can you, please, help me with any advice ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you post a picture of what you get when you rotate the device?

Comment: This might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572165/how-can-i-add-a-custom-divider-image-to-the-uitabbar

Comment: In this case, which will be the size of icons? I have 30x30 for icon.png and 60x60 for icon@2x.png

Comment: I have seen background images incorporate the separator graphic. This is something you might consider.

Answer (score 15):

I just converted [@bojanb89's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36891768/1822214) to Swift 3.  This doesn't render a background image, but simply adds a view between each tab bar item.

```
func setupTabBarSeparators() {
    let itemWidth = floor(self.tabBar.frame.size.width / CGFloat(self.tabBar.items!.count))

    // this is the separator width.  0.5px matches the line at the top of the tab bar
    let separatorWidth: CGFloat = 0.5

    // iterate through the items in the Tab Bar, except the last one
    for i in 0...(self.tabBar.items!.count - 1) {
        // make a new separator at the end of each tab bar item
        let separator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: itemWidth * CGFloat(i + 1) - CGFloat(separatorWidth / 2), y: 0, width: CGFloat(separatorWidth), height: self.tabBar.frame.size.height))

        // set the color to light gray (default line color for tab bar)
        separator.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

        self.tabBar.addSubview(separator)
    }
}
```

Comment: `int i=0; i<self.tabBar.items.count - 1` is `0..<(self.tabBar.items!.count - 1)`, not `0...(self.tabBar.items!.count - 1)`

Comment: This doesn't work. In my iphone there are offsets, also in general this approach doesn't work  - e.g. in the ipad (and maybe also landscape mode - don't remember/tested it) the tab items are not distributed equally but there's an inset at the left and right side.

Answer (score 11):

You can make programmatically a background for UITabBar:

```
#define SEPARATOR_WIDTH 0.4f
#define SEPARATOR_COLOR [UIColor whiteColor]

- (void) setupTabBarSeparators {
    CGFloat itemWidth = floor(self.tabBar.frame.size.width/self.tabBar.items.count);

    UIView *bgView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tabBar.frame.size.width, self.tabBar.frame.size.height)];
    for (int i=0; i<self.tabBar.items.count - 1; i++) {
        UIView *separator = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(itemWidth * (i +1) - SEPARATOR_WIDTH/2, 0, SEPARATOR_WIDTH, self.tabBar.frame.size.height)];
        [separator setBackgroundColor:SEPARATOR_COLOR];
        [bgView addSubview:separator];
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bgView.bounds.size);
    [bgView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *tabBarBackground = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBarBackground];
}
```

You should only extend UITabBarController and make a custom UITabBarViewController. You should call this method in viewDidLoad and in willRotateToInterfaceOrientation.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some _context_, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: This doesn't work. In my iphone there are offsets, also in general this approach doesn't work  - e.g. in the ipad (and maybe also landscape mode - don't remember/tested it) the tab items are not distributed equally but there's an inset at the left and right side.

Answer (score -1):

You can add separator on the right side of image for each `TabBarItem`. Image Size : `@1x - 64*50` (Device width - 320, Items - 5; so TabBarItem Width  = 320/5 = 64)and `@2x - 128*100` (If you have five `TabBarItems` into your TabBar).

When you rotating the device, the width of `TabBarItems` is changed.

So, You can add separator into your `image` and make effects was same as you want.

Hope, this is what you're looking for. Any concern get back to me.