# iOS custom UITabBar with Separators

Tags: ios, customization, uitabbar, uitabbaritem, separator

I have to implement a custom `Keyboard` exactly like this one.

[image]

For the categories, I've used a `UITabBar` component.
That's my current status:

[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to add the `Separator` (left/right) and the border at the bottom when one `UITabBarItem` is selected.

I've also tried some external `libraries` like that one:
[RKTabView](https://github.com/RafaelKayumov/RKTabView)

I've seen these posts:
[post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607694/add-separator-between-section-in-tabbar)
[post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572165/how-can-i-add-a-custom-divider-image-to-the-uitabbar)
 but I don't think adding a`background` `Image` with the `Separators` would solve the problem, because it also has to look fine in`landscape` mode.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: @JustSid thank you for your answer. The thing is if I knew how to implement my custom `TabBar` I wouldn't be asking here. Maybe you could provide an example?

Comment: Sorry, I can't provide you with an example, but I can link you to Apple documentation that might help along greatly: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html