# Vertical Divider Between Tabs

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tabbar, divider

How do you add a vertical divider between tabs in a tab bar controller in Swift 3? Right now, it is just the standard layout with the tab bar with all the same color.

Comment: I believe that this question was already answered.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607694/add-separator-between-section-in-tabbar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add separator between section in TabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607694/add-separator-between-section-in-tabbar)