# How to add separators to UITabbar ios

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I want to add white line separator between `UITabBarItem` on `UITabBar`.
how can I achieve this?

I have found objective-C code on the same in following link : [Add separator between section in TabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607694/add-separator-between-section-in-tabbar)

I want the c# equivalent of the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just call this method in `viewDidLoad` where you have initialized `UITabBar`

```
 private void setuptabseparator()
            {
                float itemWidth = (float)Math.Floor(this.TabBar.Frame.Size.Width / this.TabBar.Items.Length);
                UIView bgView = new UIView(new CGRect(5, 0, this.TabBar.Frame.Size.Width, this.TabBar.Frame.Size.Height - 5));
                for (int i = 0; i < this.TabBar.Items.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    float SEPARATOR_WIDTH = 0.8f;
                    UIView separator = new UIView(new CGRect((itemWidth * (i + 1) - SEPARATOR_WIDTH), 0, SEPARATOR_WIDTH, this.TabBar.Frame.Size.Height));
                    separator.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
                    bgView.AddSubview(separator);
                }
                UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(bgView.Bounds.Size);
                CGContext context = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
                bgView.Layer.RenderInContext(context);
                UIImage tabbarbackground = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                this.TabBar.BackgroundImage = tabbarbackground;

           }
```

Comment: I found I had to call this from within `ViewWillAppear` otherwise the `Items` collection was `null`.